# (Reference Request, I guess?) No-Free-Lunch Theorem for Unsupervised Learning

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, reference-request, machine-learning

I am familiar with David H. Wolpert's No-Free-Lunch Theorem for Supervised Learning. Now I am wondering: Is there some sort of such a theorem for unsupervised learning? E.g. for Clustering?

And what would such a statement on a heuristic level even mean?

I guess this is a reference request; please let me know if this is the wrong website for this, but I am looking for literature with clean proofs.

Comment: How about including a link for the existing theorem?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_in_search_and_optimization has a description and links including: Wolpert, David (1996). "The Lack of A Priori Distinctions between Learning Algorithms" (PDF). Neural Computation. Vol. 8. pp. 1341–1390. doi:10.1162/neco.1996.8.7.1341. S2CID 207609360.

Comment: This I found particularly well written: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/229078412_The_Supervised_Learning_No-Free-Lunch_Theorems